# AWS Glue transform

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Trying to read Input.csv file from s3 bucket, get distinct values ( and do some other transformations) and then writing to target.csv file but running into issues when trying to write data to Target.csv in s3 bucket.

**Below is the code:**

```
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
from awsglue.job import Job

glueContext = GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())

dfnew = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame_from_options("s3", {'paths': ["s3://bucket_name/Input.csv"] }, format="csv" )

dfMod = dfnew.select_fields(["Col2","Col3"]).toDF().distinct()

dnFrame  = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dfMod, glueContext, "test_nest")

datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dnFrame, connection_type = "s3",connection_options = {"path": "s3://bucket_name/Target.csv"}, format = "csv", transformation_ctx ="datasink")
```

**This is the data in Input.csv:**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       1       -30.4
2       2       -30.5
3       3        6.70
4       4        5.89
5       4        6.89
6       4        6.70
7       4        5.89
8       4        5.89
```

**Error:**

```
val dfmod = dfnew.select_fields(["Col2","Col3"]).toDF().distinct().show() ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/opt/amazon/bin/runscript.py", line 92, in <module>
while "runpy.py" in new_stack.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tb_frame'
```

Which I do understand comes because I am using create_dynamic_frame_from_options and not **from_catalog**
but how do I get the desired functionality while using from_options ( as my format is csv in s3) ?.

**IAM (Glue service policy):**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_Name/Output/**/**/*"
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

**S3 Bucket Policy:**

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy***",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1***",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::account_number:root"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
    }
    ]
}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

syntax error on line

```
val dfMod = dfnew.select_fields(["Col2","Col3"]).toDF().distinct().show()
```

can be corrected as follows, we don't need `val` or `show()` it will simply return a dataframe we convert it DynamicFrame before passing to `write_dynamic_frame` also need an import statement at top `from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame`

```
dfMod = dfnew.select_fields("Col2","Col3").toDF().distinct()
dnFrame  = DynamicFrame.fromDF(dfMod, glueContext, "test_nest")
```

Comment: thanks I made the edits above ( passing dnFrame to datasink params) but now now I am running into the following issue at the datasink line  : " org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 43 in stage 2.0 failed ,in stage 2.0 (executor 4): com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied" . But I am able to access Input.csv so don't know why I should be getting access denied when writing. Do the above code change look right or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you share you bucket policy and I am role policy? We must have explicit access to putObject

Comment: Sure, have added IAM and (AWS Glue service associated) Role policy above, also for "Block public access (bucket settings)" all options are set to "Off" now still getting access denied. Please suggest ?